# How to create an R package nested in git directory

Tags: r, git, devtools

I used to be able to build my R packages within my github repo, but the devtools functions have been deprecated and replaced with new functions that  won't allow me to do this anymore.

I was previously using  `devtools::setup('NewPackage', check=FALSE)` in my directory `/home/User/NewPackage/`, to create my R package `/home/User/NewPackage/NewPackage`

The new alternative gives the following error

```
usethis::create_package('NewPackage')
#New project 'NewPackage' is nested inside an existing project '/home/User/NewPackage/'
#This is rarely a good idea. Do you wish to create anyway?
#1: Negative
#2: I agree
#3: No way
```

I had automated my package creation, but this new function breaks the code in all of my packages.

I have posted this as a bug https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/553

But I am still looking for a work around or any way to automatically submit `I agree`?

### Hidden Files

There are also hidden files, such as `.Rd2pdf12059`, in my  `/home/User/NewPackage/` directory

### Sloppy Fix

Until this is fixed, I have just copied the old devtools source code and removed what I didn't like.

Comment: This seems like a better question for [usethis issues](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues) or [devtools issues](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues) since it's such a specific breaking change.

Comment: Does `create_package` think this is inside a package folder or inside an RStudio project folder? Note that `create_package` will set the working directory, so if you do it twice then the second time it will try and make a package in a package.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, I am bot sure what function thinks but I had not set the working directory before executing `create_package`

Comment: I broached this on RStudios "help" site: https://community.rstudio.com/t/multiple-package-dev-with-devtools-usethis/19207/9 and basically got told "nobody develops multiple packages". You might find some of the "withr" functionality useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest way of doing things, but you could use `testthat::with_mock` to trick `check_not_nested`:

```
testthat::with_mock(
  check_not_nested = function(path, name) return(),
  usethis::create_package('NewPackage2'),
  .env = "usethis"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `testthat::with_mock` function is now deprecated, and the functions from `mockr` or `mockery` cannot replace functions in other packages, I have found the following to work.

Note that `check_not_nested` is now named `challenge_nested_project` in the `usethis` package (version 2.0.1)

```
  challenge_nested_project <- function(path, name) return()
  
  rlang::env_unlock(env = asNamespace('usethis'))
  rlang::env_binding_unlock(env = asNamespace('usethis'))
  assign('challenge_nested_project', challenge_nested_project, envir = asNamespace('usethis'))
  rlang::env_binding_lock(env = asNamespace('usethis'))
  rlang::env_lock(asNamespace('usethis'))
```

This code does not temporarily replace the function until the package is unloaded and loaded again, and the `rlang` functions are listed as experimental, so handle with care and results might change in the future.